# Find and Replace using RegEx in SublimeText but just add formating

Tags: regex, text-editor

Using sublime text to find a model number in sublime text.  I can find the regular expression but I want to add some formatting to what it finds.  For Example, a model number may be

```
J627TS4
```

but then I want to do a find and replace and make it into.

```
<a href="#" class="popup">J627TS4</a>
```

Is this possible in SublimeText.  I have to add it to 300+ models on a chart and I am looking for an easier way.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you describe more how the model number is formatted?

Comment: I'm sorry to confuse you but my issue is not how to find the string of the model using regex but really how to replace it with the found regex in the middle of the replace. It seems to be ignoring the $1 when I put it in the replace like Alex showed in the answer below. I search \J\d+[\S]+ which finds the models correctly but when i click replace it simply puts <a href="#" class="popup"></a>

Comment: Got it. I didn't put () around the regex and it would find it but wouldn't reinsert it correctly. Putting the parenthesis allowed it to identify it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**Find:**

```
([A-Z]\d{3}[A-Z]{2}\d)
```

**Replace**

```
<a href="#" class="popup">$1</a>
```

Comment: I would just do `[A-Z0-9]{7}`, but Casimir et Hippolyte is correct – we need more info.